# Perl script is getting stuck on an if statement

Tags: perl

I'm a Perl beginner (this is my second script beyond the practise manual), and I seem to be having a bit of trouble getting an `if` statement to work.

The script is meant to read a document, take one line, parse it for a useful table (a section that starts with a text sequence and ends with `>`) and then print it to the screen.

It seems to be getting stuck after printing the first text sequence (around line 20) after printing `$line`. I added the "Just checking" in order to ascertain where the problem was occurring. Is it just something simple I am missing, or is there a flaw in my fundamental program logic?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "What file would you like to open? \n";
my $file = <STDIN>;
chop($file);
open( FILE, $file ) || die("Can not open $file");
while (<FILE>) {
    my $bool = 0;
    my $line = $_;
    chop $line;
    if ( !( $line =~ /text input/ ) && ( $bool == 0 ) ) {
        next;
    } elsif ( ( $line =~ /text input/ ) && ( $bool == 0 ) ) {
        $bool = 1;
        print $line;
        next;
    }
    if ( ( $line =~ /^\s$/ ) && ( $bool == 1 ) ) {
        print "just checking";
        next;
    }
    if ( !( $line =~ /^>/ ) && ( $bool == 1 ) ) {
        my @table = split( /\s{2,}/, my $table );
        foreach (@table) {
            print "$_ \n";
        }
        if ( ( $line =~ /^>/ ) && ( $bool == 1 ) ) {
            print "last function ok";
            last;
        }
    }
}
close($file);
exit;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting stuck"? Is it exiting? Not doing anything? And can you post your input file and desired output?

Comment: Provide your input and expected output which will make easier for the programmers to sort out your problem.

Comment: You're setting bool to zero each loop iteration.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few points that might be causing problems in your script:

```
my @table = split(/\s{2,}/, my $table);
```

Here, you're splitting a newly-initialised variable, so you're never going to get any output. You probably want to split `$line`, not `$table`.

```
while (<FILE>)
{
    my $bool = 0;
    ...
    elsif (($line  =~ /text input/) && ($bool == 0))
        {
        $bool = 1;
        next;
        }
```

You're setting `$bool` to 0 at the start of each loop, and this line, which changes the value of `$bool`, skips the rest of the loop, so none of the conditions where `$bool == 1` are going to be tested. `my $bool = 0` should go outside the while loop.

```
if (!($line =~ /^>/) ...
if (!($line =~/text input/ ...
```

You can use `$line !~ /^>/` to check that the line does not start with `>` and `$line !~ /text input/`.

```
chop $line;
```

If you want to take off the line ending, `chomp` will remove unix, win, and mac line endings.

You can take advantage of shorthand to assess the value of `$bool`, and just type

```
if ($bool)
```

Perl evaluates `0` as false and `1` as true, so you'll save at least 5 characters of typing every time you use that to assess whether `$bool` is 1. `if (! $bool)` will save three characters of typing, but it looks so much cooler, don't you think?

If that hasn't solved the problem, you will have to post your input as it's difficult to know when you want to print the table.

Comment: There are even more characters to be saved by removing `$line` and using `!/.../`

Comment: And by refactoring the loop! There's a whole soap opera's worth of characters that could be saved in this script. ;^)

Comment: Conservation of characters isn't necessary. Maximising clarity is far more important. To that end, having a boolean called `$bool` isn't good style.

Comment: @Sobrique The whole conservation of characters thing was mentioned somewhat jokingly--the point was to introduce the shorthand evaluation of a variable using `if ($var)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
while (<FILE>)
{
    my $bool = 0;
    my $line = $_;
    chop $line;
    if (!($line =~/text input/) && ($bool == 0))
```

`$bool` will always be 0 at this point.  I'm guessing maybe you meant to declare and initialize it *outside* the while loop, so it would persist over multiple lines?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to process lines between two patterns.

You can do that using a state variable `$bool`, but you will need to declare that state variable outside the file processing loop.  Currently it's being reinitialized to `0` before every line.

However, as a shortcut, you can use the [Flip-Flop Operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to look for lines between two patterns.

The following is a cleanup of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

print "What file would you like to open? \n";
chomp( my $file = <STDIN> );

open my $fh, '<', $file;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ( /text input/ ... /^>/ ) {
        print;
    }
}
```

Note:

- the Range or Flip-Flop operator returns a incrementing value that can be used to know which line number of the match you're on.
- I used the longer form of the range `...` because I wanted deferred testing of the end condition.  This is in case the `text input` line contains a `>` at the start.

As always, read the docs in detail before using a new operator or feature.

Comment: Best to add that to the explanation then.

Comment: @Miller You should add that explanation to the answer--it's far more likely that the OP will read it there and understand why you've chosen that form. I think it's better to put explanation in the answer as well as linking to the docs--a colloquial explanation is often more effective than what's in the perl docs.

Comment: @ialarmedalien Fair enough.  I figure linking to the docs is sufficient.  But I'm cool being more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a problem with these lines

```
    if (!($line =~ /^>/) && ($bool == 1))
        {
        my @table = split(/\s{2,}/, my $table);
                foreach(@table){
                    print "$_ \n";
                }
    if (($line =~ /^>/) && ($bool == 1))
        {
        print "last function ok";
        last;
        }
}
```

The last curly brace is misplaced, you never go to the line `print "last function ok";`

```
    if ($line !~ /^>/ && $bool) {
        my @table = split(/\s{2,}/, $line);
        foreach (@table) {
            print "$_ \n";
        }
    } # <=== here 
    if ($line =~ /^>/ && $bool) {
        print "last function ok\n";
        last;
    }
```